# Give an error bound for the interpolation approximation

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

The original question is as follows:

(a) Find the degree 2 interpolating polynomial P2(x) through the points (0,0),(π/2,1), and (π,0).

(b) Calculate P2(π/4), an approximation for sin(π/4).

(c) Use Theorem 3.3 to give an error bound for the approximation in part (b).

(d) Compare the actual error to your error bound.

I solved for part A using Newton's Divided Differences method. This resulted in:
$$
\begin{align*}
P_2(x) &= f[x_1] + f[x_1 x_2](x-x_1) + f[x_1 x_2 x_3](x-x_1)(x-x_2) \\
&=0 + \frac{2}{\pi} (x-0) + - \frac{4}{\pi^2} (x-0)(x-\frac{\pi}{2}) \\
&= \frac{2}{\pi}x - \frac{4}{\pi^2} x (x-\frac{\pi}{2})
\end{align*}
$$

To solve part B, I simply plugged in $\frac{\pi}{4}$. I got $P_2(\frac{\pi}{4}) = \frac{3}{4}$.

Part C is where I am having issues. I'm not sure how to give an error bound, however, the solution key provides this as the solution:
$$
\frac{\pi^3}{128} \approx 0.242
$$
**Could someone please explain how to get this solution?**

I assume to solve part D, then we can do something like this:
$$
|\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}) - P_2(\frac{\pi}{4})| = |\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - \frac{3}{4}| \approx 0.043 < 0.242
$$

Comment: The interpolation error at x is defined to be $f(x) - P(x) = \frac{(x-x_1) (x-x_2)...(x-x_n)}{n!} f^{(n)}(c)$. I understand that $n$ is simply $3$ in this case. However, I don't really understand how to get $f^{(n)}(c)$, or what it means.

Comment: I think the interval is $[0, \pi]$, and so the max of cosine must then be $cos(0) = 1$. Why is it the max of cosine and not sin though? Since $P_2(x)$ is an approximation of the sin function, shouldn't it be the max of sin? As for your second question, I think, the max can be found by taking the derivative and solving for the root. I got $x \approx 0.663897$ maximizes the function

Comment: I don't believe an original function is given. However, the interpolation should be an approximation for $sin(x)$ (as stated in part B) so I think $f(x) = sin(x)$.

Comment: How did you get the analytical result?

Comment: Sorry for all of the questions. I just don't really see anything like this in my book but the analytical result matches up with the provided solution so I do believe it is right. As I calculated earlier, $x \approx 0.663897$ maximizes $(x-0)(x-\frac{\pi}{2})(x-\pi)$. However, I don't really understand how this applies to $\frac{\pi^3}{6 \times 12\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: Oh I understand now! 1.4917... is the value that the function is maximized at; or the y value. I had solved for only the x value but never solved what the function actually maximized to. Thank you very much for the help, it makes sense to me now. If you'd like to submit an answer I will gladly accept it